# FB.login(): Unsupported Browser IE Mobile

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK in an .NET MVC mobile website. All of a sudden (since a few days) FB.login() doesn't seem to work on Windows Phone 7.8 phones. I get an error "Unsupported Browser: IE Mobile does not support this feature...".

It does work on mobile browsers on Android and IPhone.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Edward

Comment: I finally found someone with a Nokia Lumia (a lot harder than you would think) and saw this problem first hand.  I'm really surprised I can't find more examples of this issue (I'm not doing anything fancy with my Facebook connect implementation)

Comment: Can you confirm that it used to work?  In my case the issue was just that I never observed how the Facebook JavaScript SDK behaves in IE Mobile before.  I have since learned that it has never worked and that in order overcome it you need to detect IE Mobile and use a different (non-popup) login path.  Before I offer it as a answer I just wanted to be sure were are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Jason, I'm experiencing the same problem. Could you post the solution you have?

Comment: Edward, did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of unsupported browsers you should be able to fall back to use this alternative flow:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/